# Create a custom getter for an Objective-C property

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have just started learning Objective-C, and I started by making a basic program that creates a person and prints out its name. However, it doesn't work. What rookie error do you think I have made?

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Person *Bob;
    [Bob setFirstName:@"John"];
    [Bob setLastName:@"Smith"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [Bob fullName]);
}
```

Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
}

- (void) setFirstName: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setLastName: (NSString*)input;

- (NSString*) firstName;
- (NSString*) lastName;
- (NSString*) fullName;

@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

//  Getters
- (NSString*) firstName
{
    return firstName;
}
- (NSString*) lastName
{
    return lastName;
}
- (NSString*) fullName
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}

//  Setters
- (void) setFirstName:(NSString *)input
{
    firstName = input;
}
- (void) setLastName:(NSString *)input
{
    lastName = input;
}

@end
```

NOTE: This question was originally asked on Code Review StackExchange, but they closed it :-(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If the answers below have solved your question, then please accept one of them. Thank you.

Comment: @MannyFle I'm not getting an error, I'm just getting `(null)` printed to stderr instead of my object's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `@property` such as `firstName` and `lastName` you do not need to create the setters and getters, this is done automatically. For custom setters and getters you will need to create them such as for the `fullName` property. You also need to allocate and initialize your `Person` class. The following example should work:

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        Person *bob = [[Person alloc] init];
        bob.firstName = @"Bob";
        bob.lastName = @"Williams";

        NSLog(@"Full name is %@",bob.fullName);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *fullName;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (NSString *)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful and it works now. However, this has a setter for fullName, which I didn't want as it will be useless, as it always returns a value computed from firstName and lastName. How would I remove the setter?

Comment: @felixphew I think you have your getters and setters mixed up. The `fullName` method in my example is a `getter` not a `setter`. Check out this link which provides a short example of both: http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/writing-a-custom-property-getter-and-setter-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 7):

The reason it is not working is because you never allocated your `Person` object correctly.

Notice you never said `Bob = [[Person alloc]init];`. Objective-C message passing does nothing to null pointers, so that is why you did not get something such as `NullPointer`. It just silently gets ignored.